# Живые обои фоном для приложения, как?

Tags: android, livewallpaper

Как сделать живые обои, фоном для своего приложения? вдобавок пока что, я видел их только в расширение apk, как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Живые обои основываются `Surface` и рисуются внутри `SurfaceHolder`, вы можете на задний план приложения добавить такой вью и рисовать в нем все что угодно.